# Using Difference-in-Differences With No Natural Groupings

Tags: experiment-design, difference-in-difference, matching

I'm running across a number of analyses at my organization where people are doing difference-in-differences on individual-level data with no natural groupings.  For example, one looked at the effect of a particular drug on health outcomes. A number of individuals started taking the drug at different points of the year, and the analysis takes those individuals and for each one matches a control individual based on a set of covariates for the same time period, and then stacked the treatment individuals and their controls so that the start of the treatment periods overlap (i.e., one could have started in January and another in June, but for the analysis those are both treated as the start of the treatment period).  They then run a standard 2x2 DiD.

Assuming the matching is sufficient to deal with selection issues and parallel trends, is this an appropriate approach? My intuition tells me this runs into some of the issues the literature has identified with staggered adoption, but since they sort of re-center everyone in time I'm not clear on that.